# How to access a character in NSMutableString Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have an instance of `NSMutableString` called MyMutableStr and I want access its character at index 7.

For example:

```
unsigned char cMy = [(NSString*) MyMutableStr characterAtIndex:7];
```

I think this is an ugly way; it's too much code.

My question is: Are there more simple ways in Objective-C to access the character in `NSMutableString`?

Like, in C language we can access a character of a string using [ ] operator:

```
unsigned char cMy = MyMutableStr[7];
```

Comment: `characterAtIndex` returns a `unichar`, not an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of doing it is to use `characterAtIndex:`, but you don't need to cast it to a `NSString` pointer, since `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`. So it isn't that long, but if you still don't find it comfortable, I suggest to use `UTF8String` to obtain a C string over which you can iterate using the brackets operator:

```
const char* cString= [MyMutableStr UTF8String];
char first= cString[0];
```

But remember this (taken from [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String)):

> The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created.

Comment: `[str characterAt: k]` is not equivalent to `[str UTF8String][k]`. To see this, think about the result of the former, if the character at index `k` has a character code above 127. Also, `[str UTF8String]` and `str` may have totally different "logical lengths" in the presence of non-ASCII characters (i.e., characters with codes outside of 0 - 127).

Answer (score 0):

As others said characterAtIndex: but a few things you might want to consider carefully.

First you're dealing with an mutable string. You want to be careful to avoid it changing out from under you. One way is to an immutable copy and use that for the op.

Second, you're dealing with Unicode so you may want to consider normalizing your string to get a precomposed form as some visual representations may be more than one actual unichar. That's often a stumbling block for folks.